# Display default browser error message in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-messaging

I have a php script which checks my visitors traffic on my website. If its detect proxy/vpn traffic, I want  to show DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error message.

The error message display depends on the browser

On Chrome it display as "This site can't be reached"

on Internet explorer it shows  "hmmm... can't  reach this page"

Mozilla: "hmm. We're having trouble finding that site.

How do I set this error in php ? Is it possible with http_response_code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN is a domain resolution error, not a HTTP response error.

As the client has already reached the server, this error cannot be triggered.